# laravel excel import validation not giving the result

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-livewire, laravel-excel

I tried to validate excel rows by using Validator inside Laravel Excel's import class following this [laravel excel documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#gathering-all-failures-at-the-end)
But it seems the validation result not giving the results

**The Controller :** (i'm using livewire btw)

```
public function save()

{
    $this->validate();
    
    try {
        $import = new OutputImport();
        $import->import($this->excel);
    } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
        $failures = $e->failures();

        dd($failures);
    }
}
```

**The Import class :**

```
class OutputImport implements ToCollection, WithStartRow, SkipsEmptyRows
{
    use Importable;

    protected $outputs;
    protected $outputIds;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->outputs = Output::where('status',1)->get();
        $this->outputIds = $this->outputs->pluck('id')->toArray();
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
            '*.0' => ['required', function(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) {
                if (!in_array($value, $this->outputIds))
                    $fail('Periksa dan pastikan kembali ID yang diinput.');     
            }],
            '*.5' => 'required',
            '*.6' => 'required|min:0',
            '*.7' => 'required|min:0',
        ])->validate();
    }

    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The excel data is there but After the validation execution it giving me no response at all
How can i get the validation results ?

Comment: dont forget to add `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;`

Comment: I suggest reading the docs again: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#row-validation. no where on the docs a manual validator instance is created

Comment: @HerrysAghistaRachman i think it's not a Trait, so its not possible to add "use" in front of the class, if you meant the namespace, i already added it

Comment: @krisgjika i refer this docs https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#row-validation-without-tomodel section "Row Validation without ToModel" , it says we can use Validator instance

Comment: @owf do you want the import to fail if a single row fails the validation? or do you want to import only the valid rows?

Comment: @krisgjika i'd want the import failed if a single validation fails, but validation continue until the end of the rows

Comment: @owf why would that matter? you are not saving the errors anywhere. you need to get the errors from the validator instance and do what you need with them.

Comment: @krisgjika sorry my answer was confusing, the goal is to get all the errors and rollback the import once an error found, but i'll let the validation continue to finish all rows, then collect all those errors at the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255507/discussion-between-kris-gjika-and-owf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a validator instance and validate manually without throwing exceptions, via:

```php
$validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($rows->toArray(), $rules);
        
if ($validator->fails()) {
  // save messages wherever to access them later from your controller  
  $messages = $validator->errors();
} else {
  // handle your import ...
}
```

however you can't really "return" these errors from your import, especially if the import in queued. I would recommend storing these errors in a table, or cache depending on how long you intent to store them for, and display them to the user. You could create an Import model to keep track of your imports, if you do many, with fields such as status and errors.

Comment: coooool, thanks, it works !!